# Armadillo code cant compile in msys2 and netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, armadillo, msys2, openblas

I'm tring to compile a simple armadillo program by netbeans and msys2:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <armadillo>


using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(4,4);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using netbeans 8.2, msys2 installed and configured with openblas and armadillo installed by pacman. 
but I get this error:

```
cd 'D:\Users\Amir\Documents\NetBeansProjects\physics\CppApplication_2'
C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Release
"/C/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/d/Users/Amir/Documents/NetBeansProjects/physics/CppApplication_2'
"/C/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/d/Users/Amir/Documents/NetBeansProjects/physics/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Release/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -O2 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/armadillo:54,
                 from main.cpp:15:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:66:30: fatal error: C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include/hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #define ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(x) <x>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:68: build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/Users/Amir/Documents/NetBeansProjects/physics/CppApplication_2'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Users/Amir/Documents/NetBeansProjects/physics/CppApplication_2'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 575ms)
```

I also installed hdf5 in msys2. 
How can I get rid of this error?
thx.

Comment: Maybe try the mingw build of Armadillo: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-armadillo  
Related site: https://github.com/msys2/msys2

Answer (score 0):

it seems someone put this `#define ARMA_HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include/` into config.hpp in folder armadillo_bits. changing this to your usual include directory or setting it as nothing should fix the problem.